# Getting the ID of the channel a user is currently in with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm struggling to get the ID (or name) of the voice channel a user is currently in on discord.
I want to be able to move the user to a specific channel, but then move the user back to the channel it was in after a time interval.

So basically a "time out" method.

The code I have, but the *channelID* line doesn't work.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import os
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def goout(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    channelID = member.voice_channel.id

    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='Go out')
    channel2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, id=channelID)

    while True:
        await member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
        time.sleep(3)
        await member.edit(voice_channel=channel2)
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the channel in a different way/can request it in a different way.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def voice(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    voice_state = None if not member.voice else member.voice.channel
    if voice_state:
        await ctx.send(f"Name: {voice_state} / ID: {voice_state.id}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not in a voice channel.")
```

**What did we do?**

- Built in `member : discord.Member` as a needed argument
- Defined `voice_state` as our "channel" we are looking for
- `voice_state` checks if the member is in a voice channel or not
- Built in `if/else` statements to handle `None` or an actual channel

**If you want it the easy way you can use:**

```py
await ctx.send(f"{member.voice.channel}") # Gives out the name
await ctx.send(f"{member.voice.channel.id}") # Gives out the ID
```

*Note that this might just answer your question, I did not migrate it with your code!*

Comment: The ```member.voice.channel``` did the trick! But thanks for your whole input, having it in its own function is not a dumb idea